# применение псевдокласса

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<tr class="table">  
    <td>1</td>          
    <td>2</td>     
    <td>3</td> 
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>    
</tr>
```

css

```
.table td:hover{color:red}
```

как можно не принимать стили псевдокласса к конкретным элементам? В данном случае не нужно что бы работал `hover` на последний `td`

Answer (score 1):

CSS

`.table td:nth-child(1):hover{color:red}` -только к первому элементу

`.table td:nth-child(-n+4):hover{color:red}` - первые 4 шт.

Вот это Вам поможет еще http://paulradzkov.com/2014/negation_css_selector/
и это http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child